# VB.NET Close form by name

Tags: vb.net

I need to close the form by Name
I have written a detector for identifying the selected form

```
Public Function GetActive ()
         For Each form As DockContent In DockPanel1.Contents
             If form.DockHandler.Pane.ActiveContent.DockHandler.Form.Name.ToString () = form.Name.ToString () Then
                 Dim FormName As String = form.Name.ToString ()
                 Return formName
             end If
         next
         Return Nothing
     End Function
```

I need to write something on the way

```
Dim clfrm As String = GetActive
clfrm.Close()
```

Thank you for your response

// Sorry for my bad Eng.

Comment: Form.Name is already a string, all your ToString() on this property are useless.

Comment: And you can call Close when you have a Form instance not on a string.

Comment: I use class for generate new form

    Public Sub NewPage()
        Dim newpage As New CenterForm1
        newpage.MdiParent = Me
        newpage.Show(DockPanel1)
        newpage.ComID.Text = newpage.codeblock.Name
        newpage.Name = +count
        count += 1
    End Sub

Comment: `FormName Dim As String = form.Name.ToString ()` Whaaat?????????

Comment: Sorry, bad Google Translator

Comment: @ZdeněkGrůza you don't need Google Translator for code... :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```vb
Public Function CloseForm(name As String) As Boolean
    For Each form As DockContent In DockPanel1.Contents
        If form.DockHandler.Pane.ActiveContent.DockHandler.Form.Name = form.Name Then
            If form.Name = name Then
                form.Close()
                Return true
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return false
End Function
```

(untested)

Comment: Working! Thanks so much!